# getting exception error while running the Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Launch the jmeter and pass the URL am getting the exception error

2019-07-03 16:35:34,063 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.backupAndSave(Save.java:261) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:175) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.doActionNow(ActionRouter.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractAction.popupShouldSave(AbstractAction.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [?:1.8.0_212]

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when a Dependent jar is not present or in case if there is a conflicting jar with different implementation present.
Try to download a fresh copy or check that all jars are having only 1 version jmeter/lib and jmeter/lib/ext

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share me the new jmeter file link . am getting old one only

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi....Under binaries,,,go for zip if windows else tgz for linux.

Comment: Its showing error message like this "Not Found
The requested URL /[preferred]/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.1.1.tgz was not found on this server."

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi                   For me this is working fine. Try change the mirror on the same page. There is a dropdown to change mirrors and click on change button. Then try.

Comment: Try the same outside your network. It may be some issue with in the network or some restriction.